# Replacing HTML text with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, methods

I am trying to replace some html text from some code with some new text using javascript and I have learned about Javascript HTML DOM which I believe is the way to do this; however, whenever write a method, nothing seems to change. 
This is a line I am interested in changing. I want to change "Text here" to "Hello World!".

```
<a href="#" data-remote="true" data-reveal-id="login_or_create_user_modal">Text here</a>
```

This the code I used

```
 <script> document.getElementById("login_or_create_user_modal").innerHTML = "Hello World!"; </script>
```

My first concern is I have noticed that it is a data-reveal-id which is not the same as the usual id, is there a better method to use in this case? I couldn't find anything relating to data-reveal-id.

The other thing I am trying to change is to change the text cart to "Hello World!'. Again, the method I used does not do anything.

[image]

```
 <script> document.getElementById("shopping_cart_btn").innerHTML = "Hello World!"; </script>
```

Am I using the right ID or am I just completely in the wrong path here?

Thanks :)

Comment: instead of `getElementByID` use `getAttribute` to fetch data attribute

Comment: @uzaif  Would you mind expanding on this, sorry I am still fairly new in understanding javascript. From what I understand the attribute for the first case would be data-reveal-id so it would look like this :         document.getAttribute("login_or_create_user_modal").innerHTML = "Hello World!";  this doesn't seem to work though :(

Comment: what you want to achive

Answer (score 0):

for document.getElementById() to work, you need an id attribute set, try:

```
<a href="#" id="login_or_create_user_modal" data-remote="true" data-reveal-id="login_or_create_user_modal">Text here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the wrong path but you were heading the right direction. You just need to hop tracks and climb onto the `document.querySelector()` train, leaving `document.getElementById` behind for now.

`getElementById` will return an element whose `id` attribute equals the provided value; it won't look at any other attributes, like `data-reveal-id`.

`querySelector` instead uses CSS selectors to select an element. For examples of CSS selectors, refer the W3C documentation here: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

You would use this like so:

```
document.querySelector("[data-reveal-id='shopping_cart_btn']").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
```

`document.querySelector("[data-reveal-id='shopping_cart_btn']")` is saying "get me the first element you can find whose `data-reveal-id` attribute is equal to `shopping_cart_btn`.

Here's a working example to prove I'm not crazy. When the JavaScript runs, it selects the div by its data-reveal-id attribute, then replaces its inner HTML:

```js
document.querySelector("[data-reveal-id='something_random']").innerHTML = "New Text";
```

```html
<div data-reveal-id="something_random">Original Text</div>
```

Comment: This makes sense, so this would apply to the first case case right where data-reveal-id='login_or_create_user_modal'. This doesn't seem to do anything still..weird but it does make a lot more sense.

Comment: @sanjose Can you show us the code that doesn't seem to do anything? I added an executable snippet to my answer so you can see that the technique works.

Answer (score 0):

change your "data-reveal-id" to just "id" and it should work

Comment: I don't have access to that part of the code so I need to change it from outside